# como guardar una imagen en el almacenamiento interno del telefono android

Tags: java, android

Intento guardar una foto en el almacenamiento interno del telefono pero no lo he conseguido, comparto parte del codigo donde intento guardar

```
File imagenArchivo = null;
        try {
            imagenArchivo = crearImagen();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error fotografia ubicacion:" + ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (imagenArchivo != null) {
            Uri fotoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.root.xxxx.fileprovider", imagenArchivo);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fotoUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
```

```
private File crearImagen() throws IOException{
    String nombreImagen="foto_";
    File directorio=getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imagen=File.createTempFile(nombreImagen,".jpg",directorio);
    rutaImagen=imagen.getAbsolutePath();
    return imagen;
```

Comment: ¿Pediste los permisos necesarios?

Comment: si tengo los permisos adecuados pero no puedo guardar  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Con eso indicas que tu aplicación va a necesitar esos permisos. Pero necesitas que el usuario te los conceda. ¿También hiciste eso? Agrega el error que estés obteniendo a la pregunta.

Comment: simplemente no puedo guardar imagenes las tomo pero no las guardo

Comment: @Sandii no sirvió la respuesta que se tiene en esta pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

**Para crear una archivo en el almacenamiento interno del dispositivo debes usar el método `getFilesDir()`** (estás usando `getExternalFilesDir()` lo cual es incorrecto). Usando este método no podrás guardar archivos en `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`.

Por lo tanto, este sería tu método:

```
private File crearImagen() throws IOException{
       
        File imagen= new File(getFilesDir(),"foto.jpg");

        if(imagen.exists()){
            //Existe archivo
        }else{//No existe.
            try { //Crea archivo 
                imagen.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      return imagen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola agrega este método para verificar que están concedidos los permisos

int REQUEST_CODE=200;

```
    private void VerificaPermisos(){
int PermisoLeer=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

int PermisoEscribir=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            
            if(PermisoLeer== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            if(PermisoEscribir==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            
        }
```